# C program to find integer closest to 10

Tags: c

I am writing a program that will take any number of integers. The program will end when the terminal `0` has been entered. It will then output the number closest to `10` (except for the terminal character). If there are several numbers closest to `10` then it should output the last number entered.

My current code does read the numbers from the input stream, but I don't know how to implement the logic so that the program will give me the number that is closest to `10`.

I know, that I need to keep track of the minimum somehow in order to update the final result.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 1;
    int number = 1;
    int numberArray[n];
    int resultArray[n];
    int min;
    int absMin;
    int result;
    int finalResult;

    while (number != 0) {
        scanf("%d", &number);
        numberArray[n] = number;
        n++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        min = 10 - numberArray[i];
        if (min < 0) {
            absMin = -min;
        }
        else {
            absMin = min;
        }
        resultArray[i] = absMin;
        result = resultArray[0];
        if (resultArray[i] < result) {
            finalResult = resultArray[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", finalResult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specific problem do you have with the code shown? For starters, you don't need to use an array. Just keep track of the number so far that is closest to 10.

Comment: how can i track them?

Comment: @kaylum I have edited the question for OP. I could also provide an answer to OP's question. Please consider reopening the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a simple code I wrote

One thing I must say is you can't simply declare an array with unknown size and that's what you have done. Even if the no. of elements can vary, you either take input the number of elements from the user OR (like below) create an array of 100 elements or something else according to your need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_NO_WARNINGS

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    int number = 1;
    int numberArray[100];
    int resultArray[100];
    int minNumber;
    int *min;

    do {
        scanf("%d", &number);
        numberArray[n] = number;
        n++;
    }
    while (number != 0);

    resultArray[0] = 0;
    min = &resultArray[0];
    minNumber = numberArray[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if(numberArray[i]>=10){
            resultArray[i] = numberArray[i] - 10;
        }
        if(numberArray[i]<10){
            resultArray[i] = 10 - numberArray[i];
        }

        if(resultArray[i] <= *min){
            min = &resultArray[i];
            minNumber = numberArray[i];
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d",minNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have improved your script and fixed a few issues:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int number;
    int numberArray[n];
    while (scanf("%d", &number) && number != 0) {
        numberArray[n++] = number;
    }
    
    int currentNumber;
    int distance;
    int result;
    int resultIndex;
    int min = INT_MAX; // +2147483647
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        currentNumber = numberArray[i];
        distance = fabs(10 - currentNumber);
        printf("i: %d, number: %d, distance: %d\n", i, currentNumber, distance);
        
        // the operator: '<=' will make sure that it will update even if we already have 10 as result
        if (distance <= min) {
            min = distance;
            result = currentNumber;
            resultIndex = i;
        }
    }
    
    printf("The number that is closest to 10 is: %d. It is the digit nr: %d digit read from the input stream.\n", result, resultIndex + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

**Reading from the input stream:**
We can use `scanf` inside the while loop to make it more compact. Also, it will loop one time fewer because we don't start with `number = 1` which is just a placeholder - this is not the input - we don't want to loop over that step.

I used the shorthand notation `n++` it is the post-increment-operator. The operator will increase the variable by one, once the statement is executed (`numberArray` entry will be set to `number`, `n` will be increased afterwards). It does the same, in this context, as writing `n++` on a new line.

**Variables:**
We don't need that many. The interesting numbers are the result and the current minimum. Of course, we need an array with the inputs as well. That is pretty much all we need - the rest are just helper variables.

**Iteration over the input stream:**
To get the result, we can calculate the absolute distance from 10 for each entry. We then check if the distance is less than the current minimum. If it is smaller (closer to 10), then we will update the minimum, the distance will be the new minimum and I have added the `resultIndex` as well (to see which input is the best). The operator `<=` will make sure to pick the latter one if we have more than one number that has the same distance.

I have started with the minimum at the upper bound of the integer range. So this is the furthest the number can be away from the result (we only look at the absolute number value anyway so signed number don't matter).

That's pretty much it.